# Reusing Inception V3 Conv Neural Net (tensorflow) with 0% accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

EDIT1: My code is the same as here, https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception. The only difference is that I pack my files into TFRecords and feed it bactch wise. Also, the ratio of Class 0 : Class 1 is 70:30.

I'm currently working on a project in which I'm making use of inception-V3 CNN model to train a classifier. Currently, I am working on a binary classifier (either predict 1 or 0) but, my model only predicts class 0 for everything. While troubleshooting I've found that the probability of prediction is 100% for class 0 all the time. I have verified everything from the input queuing system to the eval and testing, everything seems to be working well too.

Strangely, the loss value reduces in a perfect semi-parabolic fashion which makes me think that the loss has converged to a local minima. Upon testing the script only churns out class 0(with 100% probability) each time. Another thing I've noticed is that the activation across various Conv layers are always constant which could imply that the neurons are just not firing at all.

My question is,
 1. Is my model working ? The loss seems to converge but the activation across various layers seems to be stagnant.
 2. I am using the training code available from the models section of the tensorflow (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_train.py)

I am reusing the train, eval and supporting code to train my model with a custom input pipeline created by me (which is also working). Can someone help guide me in the right direction on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your train-set is unbalanced over the 0 class. Isn't it?

Comment: I agree with @nessuno 's comment. Without having your code, it's either this, or a bug - anywhere, since your model could be wrong, as could be the loss computation, or pretty much anything else.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Ik I am a little late in answering this question

First of all your model didn't learn anything at all. All it did (cleverly ) was to predict class 0 for all cases so that it achieves a baseline accuracy of 70% without any effort. (Probably the model was lazy ) JK. This is a very well known problem in machine learning. This is called as class imbalance problem. Refer this http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/.

Apart from the techniques mentioned there. The one technique that works wonders is using class weights. That is, basically telling the network to be biased towards the weaker class. In your case class weights will be class0:class1 = 3:7. This is a hyperparameter too! But this is a good point to start.

Moreover, you didn't give any info about your dataset size. Whether you are fine tuning or training from scratch. Without them it's hard to speculate. By default I would suggest fine tuning.

Moreover, by loss you mean the training loss or validation loss? Because training loss has literally no info regarding the performance of the model. Moreover, in my opinion both training loss, and validation losses have very little info to derive meaningful insights about the model's performance. Use other metrics like confusion matrix,f1 score, recall, precision etc.

Finally, there is absolutely no single answer to your question. The only way is the hard way - you will learn along with the model . Because I consider training a NN especially a CNN an art. In which, intuition plays a very crucial role coz, most of the times, the least expected changes would give the best results. Anyway that's the fun part of training a NN.

Happy training

P.S: Try using the visualisation tools like gradcam to know whether the model is looking at the correct part of the image for classification. This is very important!